# Solving for the projection of a solution to a large linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

**Setting:** Consider a dense linear system $x = A y$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are known and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is unknown. Let $e \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be another known vector. $n$ is quite large (actually, my intended application is infinite-dimensional).

**Question:** Can I efficiently compute the inner product $\langle y, e \rangle$ without solving for all of $y$? To simplify things, we can assume that $e$ is orthogonal to the null space of $A$, so that $\langle y, e \rangle$ is unique given $x = Ay$.

**Edits:** As pointed out in the below discussion, the problem can be viewed as computing a single coordinate of $y$ (in an appropriately rotated basis). Based on this, I have also posted a closely related theoretical question here: [Solving for a single coordinate of a linear system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808127/solving-for-a-single-coordinate-of-a-linear-system).
However, in the present question, I am asking about practical approaches, allowing for approximate or randomized solutions. It would be nice to have some guarantees (e.g., fast convergence to the correct value with high probability), this isn't necessary.

Comment: Do you want a randomized approach? I'm wondering if you could instead take dot product with the solution closest to $e$ for $x=B_k y$ where $B$ is a random subset of $k$ rows of $A$, and show that this converges to true solution as $k\to \infty$

Comment: A randomized approach would be fine, as long as the convergence is reasonably robust in practice. Actually, the system $x = Ay$ is already a finite approximation of an infinite-dimensional system, where I still have to decide on the approximation. So perhaps what you are suggesting is related to choosing a good approximation. In this approach, would you sample rows uniformly? Or would it better, e.g., to sample proportional to $x$?

Comment: Actually, perhaps something better is to use [triangle inequality for cosines](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/430305/triangle-equality-for-cosine-similarity-in-high-dimensions). For simplicity, assume all vectors are norm 1, so an entry of $x$ gives an angle between a row of A and unknown $y$. Multiply that by angle between $e$ and the row to get estimate of your quantity

Comment: The other approach I suggested basically reduces to solving $x=Ay$ approximately. People usually sample rows in proportion to the norm of the row (weighted Kaczmarz). Recently some improvement was [shown](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.02910) by taking $b$ into account

Comment: Would computing the pseudo-inverse of A using the SVD and transferring all the terms to the $e$ in the inner-product (so you can compute them once and for all, help?)

Comment: @NNN If I'm understanding correctly, what you're suggesting would make sense if I had to do this for many different $y$. However, I only have to do this for a single $y$, but I think computing the pseudo-inverse of $A$ is the bottleneck ($O(n^3)$).

Answer (score 0):

More of an extended comment than a full answer -- if you rotate your linear system to coordinates where $e$ is in the direction of the first coordinate, your question reduces to asking how to obtain the first coordinate of the solution to linear system.

In other words let $y=Pw$ be the rotation of $w$ from the coordinate system where $e$ is represented in the form $\langle c, 0, 0, \ldots,\rangle$ to the original coordinate system. Now your task is to find $w_0$, the first coordinate of vector $w$ where $w$ is the solution to

$$x=APw$$

There's a simple formula to obtain $j$th coordinate of the solution to $y=Aw$ (needs checking, I copied it from [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0168927421003032#!))

$$w_j=\frac{(AP)_{\cdot,j}^Tb}{\|(AP)_{\cdot,j}\|^2}$$

Notation $M_{\cdot,j}$ refers to $j$th column of $M$

Then, you have

$$\langle y, e\rangle = w_0 c $$

This leaves open the question of how to obtain $P$

Comment: Givens rotation should do the trick. Or a Householder reflection.

Comment: I agree that my problem reduces to solving for a single coordinate of $y$ in an appropriate coordinate system. However, I don't understand the above formula for $w_j$. I suspect it might only hold if $AP$ has orthogonal columns (because then $w$ encodes the inner products of $b$ with the columns of $A$)? But, in my case, $A$ may not have any special structure.

Comment: Ok you have a point, the formula comes from a single step of coordinate descent which minimizes error by altering one coordinate and holding the rest fixed...but that might be different from the value you get in first coordinate if you were free to modify all variables

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The answer has been improved following an exchange with @YaroslavBulatov, see below.

What you seek is impossible with the current technology.

Even if the vector $y$ is given explicitly, then calculation of the inner product $y^Te$ requires $2n-1$ arithmetic operations and at least $2n$ memory operations. As a result the arithmetic intensity, i.e., the number of arithmetic operations per memory operation is less then $1$. Modern computers suffer from a phenomenon know as the memory wall. They can do many arithmetic operations in the time it takes to retrieve a single word from main memory. It follows that you cannot hope to achieve more than a tiny fraction of the peak flop rate on a modern computer. Your calculation might be perceived as fast, but it will not be efficient because the resource utilization will be poor.

You must necessarily have $x \in C(A)$ or your equation $Ay = x$ does not have a solution. Here $C(A)$ is the column space of $A$. You assume that $e \in N(A)^\perp$. Here $N(A)$ is the null space of $A$ and $N(A)^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement. Since $N(A)^\perp = C(A^T)$ we have $e = A^T s$ for some vector $s$. You wish to compute $$\nu = e^T y = (A^Ts)^T y = s^T Ay = s^T x$$ efficiently and without solving for $y$. It is certainly possible to avoid computing $y$ since $\nu = s^T x$. If you have computed a QR factorization of $A^T$, then you can obtain $s$ by solving $QRs = e$, but no modern computer that can achieve a high percentage of the peak flop rate for the general case of this problem.

There is another more fundamental issue at stake here. If a scheme could be found, then we could easily use it to solve nonsingular linear systems, but using $e = e_j$ where $e_j$ is the $j$ column of the identity matrix. The cost cannot be less than $O(n^2)$ per component or the overall solver will be faster than Gaussian elimination. In view of intense interest in solving linear systems it is highly improbably that such a scheme exists. Realistically, any viable scheme for your problem will need $O(n^2)$ arithmetic operations. You are aiming large values of $n$, so $O(n^2)$ might well be too large.

EDIT: It is clear that $y^Te$ will be a function of the entries of the matrix $A$ and the vector $x$, because $y$ is the solution of $Ay = x$. Therefore, computing $y$ will require us to at least read or generate every entry of $A$ and $x$. This requires $O(n^2)$ operations no matter what we do. If we have to read the data from memory, then we spend $O(n^2)$ memory operations. If we generate the data on the fly we still have to at least loop over all the entries and this requires at least $O(n^2)$ updates of a counter.

Comment: Would you agree that  problem in question is as most as hard as solving for a single coefficient of $y$? The question is then -- is solving for a single coefficient of $y$ cheaper than solving for all of $y$? Algebraic solution appears to have the same difficulty, but what about approximation? For stochastic approximation in $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ norm, it feels like the latter would need $O(\sqrt{n})$ more samples

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov On the contrary,  the problem is at least as hard as solving for a single component of $y$. The choice of $e = e_j$ produces the result $e^T y = e_j^T y = y_j$. Therefore, if OP's problem can be solved, then we can also compute individual components of $y$.

Comment: OK, I think we agree here. It's clear that you can't go faster than $O(n^2)$, it takes that much time just to check your matrix for NaN's

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov That is a good argument. If someone objects: "My matrices are always free of NaNs", then we counter and, say, you will need to at least read the matrix/generate the matrix on the fly and this will require $O(n^2)$ operations.

Comment: "My matrices are free of NaNs" => what is some entry is huge? "No huge entries" => this might actually make the problem easy. You might only need to read $O(r)$ rows where $r$ is effective rank of $AA'$ -- https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/W12/Lecture15Notes.pdf

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov There has been a lot of good work on randomized algorithms. However, until we learn about OP's real application it behooves us to be cautious. Many randomized algorithms have a deterministic runtime, but the results are occasionally way off mark. If there are human lives riding on the outcome, then we need algorithms where the accuracy is certain. We may be able to tolerate a nondeterministic runtime, but the accuracy must no be left to chance.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I agree that, without specific assumptions (e.g., low-rank) about the structure of $A$, one can't do better than $O(n^2)$. Perhaps I am missing something, but I thought Gaussian Elimination is $O(n^3)$? So I guess my question is now, "Is is possible to solve for a single component of $y$ in $O(n^2)$?" If it makes sense, I can edit the original question to make this more precise.

Comment: Fortunately, this is a relatively theoretical context, not a high stakes application. A method that converges to the right answer with high probability would suffice.

Comment: @sss1 I think that you should create a new question: "Let $A$ is a nonsingular dense matrix, let $b$ be a compatible vector and let $x$ denote the solution of $Ax=b$. Is it possible to compute a single component of $x$ using $O(n^2)$ arithmetic operations? Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting allows us to compute an LU factorization of $A$ and all components of $x$ using $O(n^3)$ operations, but can a single (arbitrary) component be obtained using $O(n^2)$ operations."

Comment: @sss1 I believe that the answer is no, but I would be very interested in this question and its answer.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for the suggestion, I have done so here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4808127/solving-for-a-single-coordinate-of-a-linear-system