# Solving for a single coordinate of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a nonsingular dense matrix and let $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $x = (x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n)^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be the solution of $Ax = b$ and let $j \in \{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ be given. Is it possible to compute $x_j \in \mathbb{R}$ from scratch using $O(n^2)$ arithmetic operations?

For example, Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting computes an $LU$ factorization of $A$ and *all components* of $x$ using $O(n^3)$ operations, but can the exact value of single component of $x$ be obtained from scratch using $O(n^2)$ arithmetic operations?

Some components of some linear systems are cheaper to compute than others. For example, if $A$ admits an $LU$ decomposition and $b = \beta e_n$ is a scalar times the $n$ column vector of the $n$-by-$n$ identity matrix $I_n$, then $x_n = \beta/u_{nn}$ can be computed using a single division, whereas $x_1$ can be obtained through back substitution and $O(n^2)$ arithmetic operations. The difference is not important because the cost of computing the LU decomposition is $O(n^3)$ arithmetic operations.

As suggested in the comments, it is very likely that the answer to this question is negative, i.e., it cannot be done. But can we prove that it cannot be done?

The current question grew out of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4804766/307944) on a related topic. Is possible to compute the inner product $v^Tx$ cheaply when $x$ is known only implicitly as the solution of a linear system $Ax=b$.

Comment: The answer is likely 'no'. See https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/40068/solving-for-a-single-element-of-a-solution-of-a-linear-system

Comment: Relevant https://mathoverflow.net/q/52555/110176